# What's textmate's 'Go to File' fuzzy search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, textmate, taxonomy, fuzzy-search

Textmate's 'go to file' fuzzy search is really awesome.

Wincent's Command-T plugin for vim does something similar and it rocks too.

Can someone explain how these work? Is there a general term for the method they use?

**Edit:** I little more detail about what those tools do

The tools let you narrow a list of options (in this case file paths) as you type.

For example if I had the following files:

```
/app/models/people.rb
/app/models/address.rb
/app/person.rb
/person.rb
```

to get to narrow the list to `/app/models/people.rb` I could type any of the following:

```
amp
peo
mp
modelsp
```

it's very flexible and I find my self missing this 'list narrowing' when the app I'm using doesn't have it. I'd like to learn more about it so that I may implement my own plugins if I ever felt the need. Wish I could explain it better, but that's why I'm here :)

To see it in action take a look at wincent's [demo of command-t](https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.wincent.com/command-t/screencasts/command-t-demo.mov?width=640&height=480)

Comment: Care to explain what exactly those tools do?

Comment: It's like the firefox awesomebar but for the files in your currently open project. It 'narrows down' what file you want as you type. I do find this feature to be great but I never thought much of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891514/algoritms-for-fuzzy-matching-strings

Comment: ReSharper for Visual Studio lets you use case to narrow down the CamelCasing in files.. really cool.  You can mix in wildcards as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be doing a wildcard search between every letter.

```
amp -> *a*m*p*
peo -> *p*e*o*
mp  -> *m*p*
modelsp -> ...
```

If it matches only one item in the list of options, then it would return that as the intended option.

Comment: I believe it also weights the letters near a dirsep more heavily.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Command-T does a sort based on a `double` score given by the `recursive_match` function in `match.c` to do the fuzzy search. Command-T's source is copyrighted by the author but the source can be found by opening the vimball in a text editor (download at the bottom of [this page](https://wincent.com/products/command-t)), and could probably be used as inspiration for a more general fuzzy search algorithm (by somebody who reads C better than me at least).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is the exact code you're talking about:

https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/master/Frameworks/text/src/ranker.cc

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea how this works, but for fast lookups you can generate something similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph and have O(L) complexity, where L is length of search pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote: Take a look at ([Apache Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/)) and the way it generates indexes. I find myself using it quite a bit when I am trying to implement something similar to Textmate's Command-T on the web.

Specifically check out the [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory). I believe there might even be some sourcecode somewhere. (It's in Java though…)