# Best String matching algorithm to implement in Java?

Tags: java, string-matching, similarity

I want to implement an algorithm in Java to find the nearest similar Strings.

I have **station_names** in **mysql** database like - 
**23 ST, 233 ST, 21 ST, 14 St Times Sq, 24 ST**

and if user enters a search string like **23rd station** then I should return **23 ST and 233 ST** or if user enters like **Times Square** then result should be **14 St Times Sq**.

I found many algorithms on internet but I m confused to which one to use.

**Can you please suggest me the best algorithm that can I implement in Java?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Can you please suggest me the best algorithm"*  I'd typically go for the one with polka-dots, since it is prettier.  Of course, your definition of 'better' might not include the visual effect, so why don't you tell us what *you* mean by better?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for ur reply, best algorithm means that will result most similar strings that user want to search, e.g. for 23 ST user can give search strings like 23rd Station / 23 Station / 23rd St ect

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm talks about some of the popular algorithm but you need to implement them in Java

Comment: Might help. not sure. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2891514/1135954

Comment: Thank you @AurA and mtk for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, there is no best algorithm in general, only the one that works best in your specific case.

You will want to define one or more metrics to measure differences between the input and the strings you have in the DB and then sort the results by score (see [String metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric)).

The problem is that the most similar string is not always the closest address. That's why I said you have to define your own metric.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to do this. For example you might say that `21 ST` is closer to `23rd station` than `233 ST`.  You have to work out what you want and find the approach which will match it best.

It is likely you might need multiple approaches and then score the results. This is what I would do.

You can test the different approach by providing a large sample data test suite and finding out which of the approaches (or a combination) give you the highest success rate.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answer, I want to return the most similar strings that user want to search, for e.g. for **23 ST**(actual station name) user can enter search strings - **23rd Station / 23 Station / 23rd St**

Comment: Can you define "most similar"? While it is something most people have an idea of, for a computer you need to define it formally.